# how to clear app cache using packagename

Tags: android

i googled over 1 hour ,but not found any solution. I need clear app cache using package name. Following not works for me

```
 String packageName = "some package name";
 Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
 runtime.exec("pm clear "+packageName);
```